# ROS Answers SE migration: build a map

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

who can tell me how can I build a fake 2D map, I need the data for the the map, or is there anyone can just give me the data for the 2D map (I can accept every map)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59874/build-a-map/) by [unknown](https://answers.ros.org/users/4599/unknown/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2013-04-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you mean a map like the ones created with slam gmapping? If so, you can just make a picture of how you want your map to be.

The pgm (picture) :
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/40610835/square.pgm

The corresponding yaml file :
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/40610835/square.yaml

This is a 'map' of a square area of I believe 50x50 meters.

---

Originally posted by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) with karma: 1909 on 2013-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [unknown](https://answers.ros.org/users/4599/unknown/) on 2013-04-03**:
yes, but there is nothing on the picture......I want a map!!!!

**Comment by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on 2013-04-03**:
The picture is a map, it is a square area surrounded by walls. Define what you need better if this isn't what you mean.

**Comment by [unknown](https://answers.ros.org/users/4599/unknown/) on 2013-04-15**:
yes, but i want a real map....like the first floor or second floor of a building, something like that.....